# Dynamic share into Facebook and other social media

Tags: wordpress, facebook, linkedin-api, share

I have page that creates different content with different set og:image on every page reload.
My question is how I can create a share button to Facebook and other social media like Twitter, Linkedin, who can capture this dynamic data and set the right image. Because now for example i need to run Facebook scrape btn everytime.

```
<a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://YOUR-SITE-HERE.com">Facebook</a>
```

The above is working code, just for example

Comment: Share a different URL every time that has different og:image on them

Comment: Thanks, do you mean sharing the `query` parameter, like `url=website.com?image=imagelink` ?

Comment: Yes for example.